# Put bytes from unsigned char array to std::string using memcpy() function

Tags: c++, stl, memcpy, unsigned-char

I have std::string variable. And I need to put some bytes from array of unsigned chars to it. I know the first byte and the the legth.

I can use the std::string::assign function. I've done it.

But I want to solve that issue in a right way using the memcpy function.

```
std::string newString;
memcpy(&newString, &bytes[startIndex], length);
```

I know it is wrong. I have researched and found some ideas using std::vector.

Please help me to find the most elegant solution for this issue.

Comment: Why do you think `assign()` is not the "right way"?

Comment: "in the right way" is "I know it is wrong" = ?

Comment: @Barry I want to solve it in two different ways. I am learning c++ language. And finding of this solution is interesting for me :)

Comment: @crashmstr but it can be solved using memcpy. For me like a learner is interesting how :)

Comment: @Barry The conversion from `unsigned char` to `char` is implementation-defined on platforms where `char` is signed. `memcpy` would be the way to do in a portable manner that preserves the bit patterns.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since we're just constructing the string, there is a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) constructor that takes two iterators:

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

which we can provide:

```
std::string newString(&bytes[startIndex], &bytes[startIndex] + length);
```

If we're not constructing the string and are instead assigning to an existing one, you should still prefer to use `assign()`. That is precisely what that function is for:

```
oldString.assign(&bytes[startIndex], &bytes[startIndex] + length);
```

But if you really insist on `memcpy()` for some reason, then you need to make sure that the string actually has sufficient data to be copied into. And then just copy into it using `&str[0]` as the destination address<sup>†</sup>:

```
oldString.resize(length); // make sure we have enough space!
memcpy(&oldString[0], &bytes[startIndex], length);
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Pre-C++11 there is technically no guarantee that strings are stored in memory contiguously, though in practice this was done anyway.

Comment: IDK.  looks like someone didn't like any of the answers

Comment: I think `&bytes[startIndex + length]` would be more consistent with what you have (no programmer-performed pointer arithmetic).  But there's also the string ctor taking a `const char*` and a length: `std::string newString(&bytes[startIndex], length);`

Comment: @RyanHaining OP had said that `bytes` was `unsigned char`, in which case that constructor wouldn't apply. For the other point, YMMV.

Comment: missed the `unsigned`. casting to `const char*` would seem legal in this case, meh.

Comment: @RyanHaining &bytes[startIndex + length] can result in an overflow, because you *access* the element at [startIndex + length] before taking it's address. Imagine a vector {'T'}: [startIndex (0) + length (1)] would access the element at index 1 – which is not there.

Comment: If `string::assign` performs element-wise assignment, then you run into the issue of `unsigned char` -> `char` conversions which are implementation-defined when `char` is signed. At least with `std::memcpy` you know the bit patterns will be preserved.

I'm hoping I'm wrong, because I'm encountering a similar issue when copying UTF-8 bytes to `std::string`, the latter still being used heavily in APIs until `std::u8string` becomes mainstream.

Comment: @EmileCormier Accessing `s[0]` on an empty string is fine, you get back `\0`. I rolled back your edits.

Comment: @Barry Oops, forgot about the automatic `\0` terminating character! :-)

Comment: I'm a rookie in c++, I have some question that memcpy with string .

Are you sure that  ``` memcpy(&oldString[0], &bytes[startIndex], length);``` is a allowed function by c++? 

Do you consider compatibility with gnu/g++ and so on . or diff version with c++ ?

@Barry

Comment: In other words, Do you guarantee string has contiguous storage?@Barry

Comment: @zhaozheng `std::string` guarantees contiguous storage, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the size of the string so that there will be a properly sized buffer to receive the data, and cast the constness out of the pointer you get from `data()`

```
std::string newString;
newString.resize(length);
memcpy((char*)newString.data(), &bytes[startIndex], length);
```

of course all of this is in the realm of undefined behavior, but pretty standard non the less.

Answer (score -1):

It's a hack and as you said wrong way but it is possible since STL guarantees that `std::string` has contiguous storage:

```cpp
std::string str(32, '\0');
std::strcpy(const_cast<char*>(str.data()), "REALLY DUDE, IT'S ILLEGAL WAY");
```

Of course, you can use `std::memcpy` in the same way (I used `strcpy` just to copy null-terminated string)...

In your case:

```cpp
str.resize(length);
memcpy(const_cast<char*>(str.data()), bytes + startIndex, length);
```

Comment: And if the string you're copying has more than 32 bytes?

Comment: Of course, you should 'presize' well fit string (pay attention, `resize()` not `reserve()`!)

Comment: to clarify what Nevermore means by "illegal way": [*Modifying the character array accessed through data is undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).  Don't do this

Comment: from `STL guarantees that std::string has contiguous storage` does not follow you can modify what `data()` returns

Comment: from `does not follow you can modify what data() returns` actually doesn't follow I can not modify what `data()` returns. This issue **has no legal solution** and I **pointed** that it's a hack. Do you wanna see another hack like `&front()` instead of `data()` or what?